# A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php

I'm working on a project in which I need to match two dates. One stored in the database and one is the current date time. I've decided to use unix timestamp for this. I'll convert these both values to unix timestamp and would then compare.

I used the below code to generate the unixtimestamp, but it gave me the following error :-
 **A non well formed numeric value encountered**

I have gone through half a dozen questions on stack overflow, but none helped my case.

```
$date =date("Y-m-d H:i:s A");
echo mktime($date);
```

What might be the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong function, you don't want to use `mktime` but [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$date =date("Y-m-d H:i:s A");
echo strtotime($date);
```

But the format of the date you are passing isn't currently supported by PHP. You'll have to drop `A` (`PM` and `AM`).

To drop the AM/PM:

```
echo strtotime(substr($date, 0, -2));
```

Comment: Ok, isn't there any function to make a unix timestamp including the AM or PM ?

Comment: I don't think so. But your date is in 24h format, just drop the AM/PM and pass it to strtotime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the current unix time, just use mktime() with no arguments. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php